# Handle mouse events in QGrahpicsItem but ignore mouse move events

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qgraphicsitem

I have a subclass of `QGraphicsItem` inside a `QGraphicsScene`. To handle mouse events inside the item, I reimplemented `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`. Since I want the item to be movable, I wrote `setFlags(ItemIsMovable);` inside my constructor. But when I move the item, my `mouseXxxEvent` methods are called as well.

**How can I detect whether the mouse event was used to move the item or not?** I would be ok to only reimplement one of the above mentioned functions.

Comment: If you override one of the mouse events, you should override all of them. If you want the default behaviour, just call the parent class's function.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight That still doesn't help me. I can override all functions without knowing whether the mouse was moved or can I? And I don't think mouse press will help because the Qt can't guess whether the user will do a normal click or move or drag or whatever

Comment: You could use the `itemChange` virtual function and watch for `ItemPositionHasChanged` events (you have to set the `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag). This tells you that the item was just moved.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Thanks, that works, but why don't I use `ItemSendsScenePositionChanges` instead of `ItemSendsGeometryChanges`?

Comment: One option may be to create an event filter object, applied to all items in the scene, which detects movement of any item.